# Change Tag of a topic in Documentation

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, documentation-editor

I added a topic documentation in CSS instead of ASP.NET. How can i change its Tag from CSS to ASP.NET ?

I tried all Edit options but didn't find Tag Edit.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That question is completely difficult to search. I made a search and didn't find that. People should ask question in a simple and common way, so that others are able to find it easily. Specially for non-english.